# Al borrar un campo id, no se restructura los campos id en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Al borrar un campo id, función que tengo implementada en el constructor, y que es llamada por la vista delete, que es un botón, al borrar un campo no se restructura los campos id en laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deberían de aparecer 1 y 2.

Este es el método del constructor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque es el ID que tiene en la base de datos

Comment: y como puedo hacer para que se reordenen?

Comment: ¿Para qué quieres que se reordenen?

Comment: porque asi, no tengo ningun id vacio

Comment: @Sal A lo que se refiere con "reordenarlos" es a que si tiene los ID `1, 2, 3, 4` y elimina el 2, en vez de quedar `1, 3, 4` se actualicen los IDs quedando `1, 2, 3`

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema al haber ese *“id vacio”*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nivel de Base de datos no es buena idea modificar los Ids de los registros pues estos comúnmente estan relacionados a otras tablas, además de que generan una sobrecarga de recursos en caso tal de que una tabla tenga 1 millón de registros y tu borras el Id 5, eso significa que debes modificar los Ids de muchos registros innecesariamente.

Si la tabla no va a crecer mucho y no sobrecarga el servidor puede ser algo así, pero ojo recordar que la tabla no debe tener como llave primaria el id.

```
$especialidades = ModeloEspecialidades:::Where('id_tratamiento' ,'>', $objetoEspecialidades->Id_tratamiento)->get();
foreach($especialidades as $especialidad) {
$especialidad->Id_tratamiento = $especialidad->Id_tratamiento - 1;
$especialidad->save()
}
```

Nota: Según la versión de laravel puede que necesite algunos cambios o mejoras pero ya tu lo ajustas.

Otra forma sin modificar la tabla seria a nivel de la vista, Indexar los registros antes de mostrarlos para que este sea el que aparece visualmente no te paso ejemplo porque no se como generas la vista.